# How to enumerate all photos on iOS 8 using ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: ios, ios8, photo, alassetslibrary, alasset

iOS 8 broke lots of apps by removing "Camera Roll" from the ALAssetsLibrary enumerating API. I know I can get all photos using the new Photos framework. But my app has a lot of code depending on ALAsset related classes and I need to keep iOS 7 support. Is there a way to enumerate all photos using ALAssetsLibary on iOS 8, without enumerating asset group first?

Comment: May want to check my ios 8 update in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8872425/394736 that may help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple just released 8.0.1 and listed this as a included fix. Might just be best to wait for that.

From the 8.0.1 release notes:
`Fixes an issue that prevented some apps from accessing photos from the Photo Library`

Comment: For me iOS 8.0.2 made things even worse. "Recently Added" now is called "Photos" when received through ALAssetsLibrary, includes some pictures not included in the photo app and misses some others. Great!