# ALAssetLibrary , it only shows partial number of photos in All Photos on some devices

Tags: ios, photos, alassetslibrary, phasset

I used to use ALAsset, it works well for iOS7~iOS9 for most users (about 100K) .
    But some users complain it only show partial number of photos on i6 device, ios8/ios9. (Maybe 1% has this problem, I'm not sure.)

I have the i6 ios9 device, but my device can't show the the same problem. Users said App only show photos for the two month past. How does it happen ?

For their device, they don't have camera roll album, but mime has. I'm not sure if it cause the problem. How to solve this problem ?   Should I change to PHAsset Photos from iOS8.

Comment: might be similar with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945002/how-to-enumerate-all-photos-on-ios-8-using-alassetslibrary)? also check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867496/get-last-image-from-photos-app/8872425#8872425), might be helpful..

Comment: I don't think it's the same problem, but it's related. When the device has camera roll album , all the photos can be loaded correctly in "camera roll" album group.  But for the device without camera roll , some of the photos can cannot be  loaded in "All Photos" album.  The device are upgraded to ios9.2.1. Anyway, I don't know the solution. I use the common implementation for alassetgroup.          NSUInteger groupTypes = ALAssetsGroupAll;
    [assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:listGroupBlock failureBlock:failureBlock];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause, which ALAssetLibrary can't read some photos for iOS8/iOS9. It result from that iCloud is enabled and optimize for storage is chosen.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264
On your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, tap Settings > iCloud > Photos or Settings > Photos & Camera, then select a storage setting.   turn on Optimize [device] Storage.

So, ALAssetLibrary can't read these photos uploaded to iCloud. For users to workaround.
  1. he can use Photos app to edit the photo rotate and rotated back save. And ALAssetLibrary can read again.
  2. disable Optimize device Storage and connect wifi & power. the photo will be pulled back to device from iCloud.

For programming side, I think the only way is to use Photos/PHAsset for iOS8/iOS9. Photos framework can read thumbnail and original from iCloud.

Do you have other solutions?