# Getting Last Image of Album using Xamarin.IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to get the last image from the album and share it on social media but whenever I tried searching for solutions, they are all either in Objective-C or Swift and I don't really understand either of the language.

I searched for solutions and got this which is in Objective-C:
[Get last image from Photos.app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867496/get-last-image-from-photos-app)

and I have problems trying to convert the code myself from Objective-C to C# in Xamarin.IOS

The main problem that I got stuck with when converting is this line

```
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
```

I could not find sortDescriptorWithKey anywhere in Xamarin.IOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the constructor according to the documentation: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Foundation.NSSortDescriptor/#Public_Constructors

so something like:

```
fetchOptions.SortDescriptors = new NSSortDescriptor[] {new NSSortDescriptor("creationDate", false)};
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, but I'm still having a small problem, it is now saying: "cannot implicitly convert type Foundation.NSSortDescriptor to Foundation.NSSortDescriptor[]"

Comment: SortDescriptors expects an array i assume, you only return 1 instance and not an array of NSSortDescriptors. What the objective c does in your example is its wraps the one instance in a array by using the []. In C# it would be something like: fetchOptions.SortDescriptors = new NSSortDescriptor[] {new NSSortDescriptor("creationDate", false)};